# xslt loop inside src of an img google charts

Tags: xml, xslt, google-visualization

i need to create a google chart from an xml using xslt.

ive done this before using short hand, this was good if i had only one node value but i need to loop trough the nodes.

```
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
cht=bvg&amp;chs=350x300&amp;chd=t:20,35,10&amp;
chxr=1,0,40&amp;chds=0,40&amp;
chco=ff0000|ffa000|00ff00&amp;
chbh=65,0,35&amp;
chxt=x,y,x&amp;chxl=0:|<xsl:for-each select="node/ROW"><xsl:value-of select="node"/>|</xsl:for-each> ||&amp;chxs=2,000000,12&amp;
chtt=Tasks+on+my+To+Do+list&amp;chts=000000,20&amp;
chg=0,25,5,5" alt=""/>
```

thats the loop(an eample of a loop): `<xsl:for-each select="node/ROW">  <xsl:value-of select="node"/> |</xsl:for-each>`
i will need to put it in some of the google chart vars like chxl=...etc
maybe ill need more loops fore other data.

for now it returns only syntax errors.

if you have another way of implementing it go ahad.
i searched all over the net about google charts and xsl and found a vage tut and an non-functional code in github.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying this:

```
<xsl:variable name="cells">
  <xsl:for-each select="node/ROW">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(node, '|')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
cht=bvg&amp;chs=350x300&amp;chd=t:20,35,10&amp;
chxr=1,0,40&amp;chds=0,40&amp;
chco=ff0000|ffa000|00ff00&amp;
chbh=65,0,35&amp;
chxt=x,y,x&amp;chxl=0:|{$cells} ||&amp;chxs=2,000000,12&amp;
chtt=Tasks+on+my+To+Do+list&amp;chts=000000,20&amp;
chg=0,25,5,5" alt=""/>
```

Comment: looks like wat i was looking for, i wanted to put what i got in a variable but didnt know how thanks

Comment: @rolen you should think about accepting some of your answers.